# Passing User Variables to Worksheet Functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a string from a user text entry box(TextBox1) and use it to alter inventory counts.

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

    'make inventory sheet active
Worksheets("Inventory").Activate


    'declare the part number and quantity as variables

    'set variables to user values


    'This is a test to make sure the variables work. delete this later
    'locate cell associated with part number
    'This works
Sheet5.Range("j9") = TextBox1.Value

    'This works
Sheet5.Range("j10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1234, Sheet5.Range("D5:D8"), 0)

    'This does not work
Sheet5.Range("j7") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, Sheet5.Range("D5:D8"), 0)
    
    'locate inventory cell associated with part number
    
    'if transact is selected:
    'alter inventory by -1(QTY)
    'record action in reciept tab
    
    
    'if restock is selected:
    'alter inventory by +1(QTY)
    'record action in reciept tab
  

End Sub
```

Im currently stuck just trying to get the match function to work. When I run this I get:

"Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Match property of the Worksheet Function class"

In this case, I am looking for part number "1234". When i print the output of the text box to a cell, it reads 1234. when I match for it dirrectly, it outputs the correct index. when i try to match for the use input dirrectly, it fails. I also tried storing the user input as a variant first with no luck

Comment: Try `CLng(TextBox1.Value)`. Also, rather use `Application.Match` (without `WorksheetFunction`) so the mentioned error is not raised when there is no match, e.g. `Sheet5.Range("J7").Value = Application.IfNA(Application.Match(CLng(TextBox1.Value), Sheet5.Range("D5:D8"), 0), "")`.

Comment: [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) might be better.

Answer (score 0):

WorksheetFunction.Match is sensitive for the lookup_value type. This error message is generated if the types are different. E.g. The values in the cell are numbers and you are looking for a string.

```
This looks for a number

WorksheetFunction.Match(1234,range("A1:A10"),0)

This looks for a string

WorksheetFunction.Match("1234",range("A1:A10"),0)
```

The TextBox.Value return a string. In your example the value in the cell is a number. Therefore convert the lookup_value to a number something like this.

`WorksheetFunction.Match (CDbl(TextBox1.Value), Sheet5.Range("D5:D8"), 0)`